# cannot connect Django to postgres

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am trying to connect my django app to postgres but it gives the following error.

```
connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "testDB" does not exist
```

the postgres server is running I have checked it also restarted the server still I get the same error

my database settings.

```
  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
          'NAME': 'testDB',
          'USER': 'postgres',
          'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
          'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
          'PORT': '5432',
      }
  }
```

I tried to check if the server is running and it is running, also restarted the server but still the same error.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  Did you attempt to create a database with that name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`database "testDB" does not exist`

If you want to connect to database "testDB", it should exist.
But it isn't.

Try to create db with name "testDB" by command like, like this,

```
create database 'testDB';
```

or in pgadmin.

Comment: I thought it would be automatically created. (Beginners doubt)

Answer (score 0):

did your Postgres DB hosted in the correct IP? , Check the info there is a mistake surely

Comment: yes the IP is correct